# Html language in "less" style

Tags: html, compiler-construction, less

I've seen Less code and it's pretty easy to understand and fast compared to Cascading Style Sheets, is there something similar for HTML?

Comment: Have you looked into Emmet?

Comment: jade is a pretty popular option

Comment: If you're using rails, [Haml](http://haml.info/)

Comment: There are some options here.
If you want to code html fast, you should go with [Emmet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxW-V24MTXI).

Now, if you want to have the same behavior that less perform with css, you should check [Haml](http://haml.info/). To work with Haml, you can use [Grunt](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-haml), that will compile that for you.

If you are using [Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), you could use the [Haml Gem](https://github.com/haml/haml). Another great template engine for Rails is [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look up "[Haml](http://haml.info/)" or "[Slim](http://slim-lang.com/)".